# ASP Crystal Reports asks for database credentials after changing to HTTPS

Tags: crystal-reports

I know this question has been asked several times but I have a slight variance on it that I have been trying to resolve.

I have crystal reports running on an old web system written in classic asp. All the reports have been running without problems for several years, however recently security was improved so that the system is now accessed over HTTPS. Since this change the reports have all started asking for the database credentials. If SSL is disabled so that it returns to regular HTTP then they start working again.

The system was created by another developer who has since moved on so I am not very familiar with it, but as far as I am aware the reports are all set to use a System DSN set up in the control panel of the server that IIS is running on. The database is located on a separate server.

Does anybody have a suggestion as to why the reports would start asking for database credentials after changing to HTTPS and how to resolve it? I will not be able to make any code changes to the application as the source code is not available but I can modify the reports and play with connection settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. The site was running HTTPS but the button for the report was in a form which submitted to HTTP and then was redirected back to HTTPS. This was causing a loss of the session information or something like that. Fortunately the forms action url was stored in the database so it was a simple matter to resolve.